# Re sizing columns with restriction in CSS

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

So I have a weird question. This is what I have [so far](http://jsfiddle.net/jm0kres4/1/). In the jfiddle, there's 3 columns of words, but in reality, I will be between 2 and 5.
The problem is the columns can be long, but short in width. What I'd like is to be able to use the rest of the white space for the columns. I read [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/) which gave me some suggestions and I added the following to the column divs:

```
div {
  -webkit-columns: 2 200px;
  -moz-columns: 2 200px;
  columns: 2 200px;
float:left;
}
```

However, it doesn't give me what I want, because when the page changes size, the columns go under each other, which is absolutely BAD. Is there any way I can have the columns (divs) wrap to take up any white space, but if the page becomes too small, then each div should be comprised of one column, and there should be horizontal scrolling.

In essence, I have 2 questions:

1)I don't want the divs to go underneath each other when the page resizes BUT
2) if there is white space, I'd like the divs to split and take up that empty space.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see if using the column CSS is good enough with only setting the width of the colums: (run the code snippet below or [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm0kres4/3/) )

```css
section {
    padding: 1em;
    -moz-column-width:5em;
    -webkit-column-width:5em;
    column-width:5em;
}
span {
    display: block;
    width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div><span>column a</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>last word</span></div>

    <div><span>column b</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>last word</span></div>

    <div><span>column c</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>word</span><span>last word</span></div>    

  
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I only need the column width, but the columns still go underneath each other when the page resizes or if there's too many columns, which I'd like to avoid at ALL costs because the content in each columns is so different from the other columns.

Comment: @thatandrey then, you may do a mixed of inline-boxe and column : http://jsfiddle.net/jm0kres4/4/ http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/jm0kres4/6/

Comment: Thanks! That is sooo close to what I want! The only issue is that when you resize the page to make it very small, the columns will go underneath each other. Is there any way to prevent that behavior?

Comment: I also noticed that width: 30% was set, but I will have a variable number of columns on each reload (from 2-5). Is there any way to take that into account?

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/jm0kres4/8/ ? last option is to set a class within the script that generates countent, counting number of blocks you insert, class set on parent. or on child with a max-width ...

Comment: sorry for replying late, I had a class. For one of your jfiddles, I updated it to see how it would work with a small column and noticed the results weren't being displayed downward, but rather left to right: http://jsfiddle.net/jm0kres4/9/. I combined some earlier solutions to get this, and it seems to work, but if a column is small, there's some weird white space that I can't get rid of, so I'll post a new question for that: http://jsfiddle.net/jm0kres4/10/. What do you think? Any suggestions to make it work a little better?

Comment: I put a new question here if you'd like to answer it cuz I'm not sure how to tackle it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824098/weird-quirk-when-re-sizing-columns-with-css