# Weird quirk when re sizing columns with css

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I posted an earlier question about making having columns wrap in a way that utilizes the most space in the viewport, right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822009/re-sizing-columns-with-restriction-in-css). Combining some of the answers, I came up with the following [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm0kres4/11/). I will be having a variable number of columns (2-5) and a variable number of words in each column. If you resize the jfiddle window horizontally, you'll notice that the middle column uses a third of the viewport even though there are barely any words in there, essentially leaving empty white space. I wouldn't mind using jquery/js, but I'd like to have the columns more smartly resized.

The current CSS I have is

```
body {
    padding: 1em;
    display: table;

    width: 100%;
}
div {
    display: table-cell;
        -moz-column-width:7em;
    -webkit-column-width:7em;
    column-width:7em;
}
span {
    display: block;
    width: 5em;
}
```

The body is the container, and the divs represent the columns, and the spans are the words in each column. The only thing I want to avoid at all costs is having the columns go underneath each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns act the way they do because they are equal in size. You have a single style for div so all columns get the same styling rules applied and (in your fiddle) equally share the width getting 1/3 of the horizontal space each.

Only having 7 entries in Column B means that it doesn't reach the bottom so does not wrap into inside the div like the other columns with more contents, so cannot use the additional space.

It not really a case of "even though there are barely any words in there" its because "there are barely any words in there" - there is not enough content to wrap into the space based on the height of the table cells.

The height of the cell is determined by the contents of all three columns and how they wrap. So whichever column has the most words will wrap its contents until is takes up a amount of space vertically on the page. This is then the height for the entire table and all three columns. If either of the other two columns don't have enough content to wrap they will leave space.

If you double the number of words in columns A for example you can easily get a situation where there is "left space" in both column B and column C.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it made sense, but what can I change to account for variable column widths, because I would very much like to get rid of the white space somehow...

Comment: You will need to find the column with the least number of words and to this  add a class of "least" when you render into the mark-up. You could then run a bit of script that checks the width of the browser and sets the width of $('.least') to 5em when only one column will fit, 10em when you can fit two and so on.

Comment: You can achieve an effect part way to this with body {
    padding: 1em;
    display: table;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
div {
    display: table-cell;
    -moz-column-width:7em;
    -webkit-column-width:7em;
    column-width:7em;
}
span {
    display: block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:center;
}
.least {
    width: 10em;
}

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do that, but my columns are variable because they're coming from a data base, and I'm sort of outputting one column at a time. Is there any way I can do the computations in real time, or something?

Comment: It's not really efficient to get them them from the database a column at a time, that multiple requests. You could get them all at the same time, write a proc or union to do that (in one go). Then you can get the counts upfront and work on your data. If you don;t want to swap over to single read then you need to track which is minimum and then add that to the span that matches nth-child(col) and then .addClass('least')

Comment: What I'm doing now is actually probably bad practice. I have a function that gets each column, and echoes out the html code for each row. Should I just append all the html code to a string and then echo that when I've done all the columns? Do you know any resources on best practices or examples? I'm not sure if a union will work for my needs because I'd like the columns to be separated and from my understanding, once I do a union, I won't be able to distinguish which result belongs to which column.

Comment: A union just means that you get more than one set of data and combine them into a large set of data. What the structure of that data is like is totally yours to decide - it could be 1 row of data for each column that  you want or it could be multiple columns of data that matches the number of columns that you have. Best practice  depends on what you're trying to do and often there are 10's if not 100's of ways to do it - you can only really say better or worse and then only against a criterion that if you measure,  But which would you choose?

Comment: I changed the code, and now I append all the data to a string before I echo it, which should help a lot with the automatic resizing issue. For now, I'll probably keep the the queries separate so I have more control while I'm still changing and testing the code. Thanks for all the help!